# expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Tags: python

I keep getting expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple when trying to open a chrome window and then have it go to instagram.com. I am practicing python by creating a bot and curious why it is giving me this err, any help would be appreciated. The compiler is located the error on the line of code that reads "self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverDownloader().download_and_install())"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriverdownloader import ChromeDriverDownloader
import os
import time

class InstagramBot:

    #Does this code when program is ran
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        #Creates username and password of user
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        #Opens chrome driver which opens chrome
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverDownloader().download_and_install())

        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ig_bot = InstagramBot('temp_username', 'temp_password')
```

Answer (score 1):

`ChromeDriverDownloader().download_and_install()` returns a tuple.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/leonidessaguisagjr/webdriverdownloader/blob/master/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py#L158):

```
def download_and_install(self, version="latest", os_name=None, bitness=None, show_progress_bar=True):
    """
    Method for downloading a web driver binary, extracting it into the download directory and creating a symlink
    to the binary in the link directory.
    :param version: String representing the version of the web driver binary to download.  For example, "2.38".
                    Default if no version is specified is "latest".  The version string should match the version
                    as specified on the download page of the webdriver binary.
    :param os_name: Name of the OS to download the web driver binary for, as a str.  If not specified, we will use
                    platform.system() to get the OS.
    :param bitness: Bitness of the web driver binary to download, as a str e.g. "32", "64".  If not specified, we
                    will try to guess the bitness by using util.get_architecture_bitness().
    :param show_progress_bar: Boolean (default=True) indicating if a progress bar should be shown in the console.
    :returns: Tuple containing the path + filename to [0] the extracted binary, and [1] the symlink to the
              extracted binary.
```

Comment: So what would you recommend doing to fix it? Im relatively new to python

Comment: You will need to extract one of the values from the tuple and use that. Which value you need is something you will need to determine. Values of a tuple can be accessed the same way as values from an array, using `myTuple[<index>]`